# How to fix HTTP parameter/path pollution attack Spring Rest

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

Extracting parameters from HTTP message and getting resource URLs could be vulnerable to injection attacks that may change the semantics of the intended resource. Two classes of attacks are relevant here: HTTP parameter/path pollution (HPPP) and Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF). Remember that our attacker has full control over the HTTP request or the HTTP response.

In an HPPP (HTTP parameter/path pollution attack), a parameter is used to compose the resource URL to be used to prepare a REST request for a resource (or generate an embedded link). The problem is that the attacker may either alter the path or add/overwrite unexpected parameters in the “query string”. Additionally, REST frameworks may use a parameter (like _method) to allow the specification of a REST verb different from the incoming HTTP method, so a GET request could be interpreted as a PUT operation. An attacker may change the semantics of the REST resource URL.

find more info [here](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~vpk/papers/arc.acns12.pdf)

**Example :**

For example: if testing the search_string parameter in the query string, the request URL would include that parameter name and value.

```
http://example.com/?search_string=kittens
```

The particular parameter might be hidden among several other parameters, but the approach is the same; leave the other parameters in place and append the duplicate.

```
http://example.com/?mode=guest&search_string=kittens&num_results=100
```

Append the same parameter with a different value

```
http://example.com/?mode=guest&search_string=kittens&num_results=100&search_string=puppies
```

and submit the new request.

**Question:**

Spring Rest ,Spring MVC and Spring Security doesn't provide any in built support to fix HPPP issue.How can we fix inside of Spring frameworks ?

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Comment: I've never heard of path pollution attacks before. Do you have any references? Parameter pollution should be avoided automatically at the servlet container level, but you would still be wise to test areas of your application that consume (parts of) the query string

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Although this is pretty old and I assume, you now have heard of it, here is a reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_(OTG-INPVAL-004) Based on this, Tomcat returns the first occurrence. When it's always done like that, I don't see a way to exploit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few hours , i have implemented following solution , let me know if you have any better approach to handle it.

1) I  have added CustomHandler which implements HandlerInterceptor

2) Overriding preHandle method to read all input parameters

3) If input parameters not exist in my predefined list then throw exception.

**Code :**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Component
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    enum parameterChoices {
        inputParam1, inputParam2, inputParam3
    };

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        if (request.getParameterNames() != null) {
            Enumeration<String> parametrs = request.getParameterNames();
            List<String> list = Collections.list(parametrs);
            ListIterator<String> litr = list.listIterator();

            while (litr.hasNext()) {

                if (!contains(litr.next())) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("HTTP parameter/path pollution attack Exception");
                }
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---method executed---");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---Request Completed---");
    }

    private boolean contains(String paramValue) {
        System.out.println("contains paramValue=" + paramValue);
        if (paramValue == null || paramValue == "") {
            return false;
        }

        for (parameterChoices type : parameterChoices.values()) {
            if (type.name().equals(paramValue)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Now Register:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor ;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor );

    }
}
```